# Reordering all slides

Tags: node.js, google-slides-api

I have a NodeJS app I am writing that will manipulate slides in my Google Slides Presentation.  I am trying to reorder all the slides in my Google Slides presentation at one time.  I keep getting this error: `reason: GaxiosError: Invalid requests[0].updateSlidesPosition: The slides should be in presentation order, with no duplicates.`  I don't even know what "in presentation order" means.

I have 11 slides in my presentation with ID's looking like `"Sermon-Slide-9","Sermon-Slide-3","Sermon-Slide-0", "Sermon-Slide-1", etc`.  And I wanted them placed in numerical order so `Sermon-Slide-0, Sermon-Slide-1, Sermon-Slide-2, etc`.

Here is the function that is doing the reordering:

```js
const reorderSlidesNumerically = async (slideCount, slidesApi, fileID) => {
  let slideObjectIds = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
    slideObjectIds.push('Sermon-Slide-' + i);
  }

  console.log({ slideObjectIds });
  const requests = [{
    "updateSlidesPosition": {
      "slideObjectIds": [...slideObjectIds],
      "insertionIndex": 0
    }
  }];
  console.log({requests});
  const batchUpdateRequest = { requests };
  await slidesApi.presentations.batchUpdate({
    presentationId: fileID,
    requestBody: batchUpdateRequest,
  });
};
```

And here is part of the response I am receiving back:

```
 body: '{"requests":[{"updateSlidesPosition":{"slideObjectIds":["Sermon-Slide-0","Sermon-Slide-1","Sermon-Slide-2","Sermon-Slide-3","Sermon-Slide-4","Sermon-Slide-5","Sermon-Slide-6","Sermon-Slide-7","Sermon-Slide-8","Sermon-Slide-9","Sermon-Slide-10"],"insertionIndex":0}}]}',
    responseType: 'json',
    retryConfig: {
      currentRetryAttempt: 0,
      retry: 3,
      httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
      noResponseRetries: 2,
      statusCodesToRetry: [Array]
    }
  },
  code: 400,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Invalid requests[0].updateSlidesPosition: The slides should be in presentation order, with no duplicates.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of creating custom object ids for your slides, such as on this line `slideObjectIds.push('Sermon-Slide-' + i)`? It seems like the error *`"Invalid requests[0].updateSlidesPosition: The slides should be in presentation order, with no duplicates."`* is because these`objectId`s are apparently non-existing when used in the `batchUpdate` call.

Comment: I made custom object ID's for each of the slides so it would be easier to work with them in my app.  So I know which one I'm working with and what spot it is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your error message of `Invalid requests[0].updateSlidesPosition: The slides should be in presentation order, with no duplicates.` and your request body, I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to that all slides are inserted to one index of `"insertionIndex": 0`. I thought that the slide of the index of `0` is included in `slideObjectIds` in your situation. In this case, it seems that when your request body is used, such an error occurs.

In order to avoid this, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const requests = [{
  "updateSlidesPosition": {
    "slideObjectIds": [...slideObjectIds],
    "insertionIndex": 0
  }
}];
```

#### To:

```
const requests = slideObjectIds.reverse().map((e) => ({
  updateSlidesPosition: { slideObjectIds: [e], insertionIndex: 0 },
}));
```

- In this case, this request can be done by one API call.

#### Reference:

- [UpdateSlidesPositionRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateslidespositionrequest)